# How to limit internet speed?

Tags: internet, networking

I have 3 accounts in my pc, i would like as the admin of the pc to limit the internet speed (upload/download) for the other 2 accounts, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Wondershaper POWER!!!

Here is a tutorial - http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-bandwidth-shapers-wondershaper-or-trickle-to-limit-internet-connection-speed.html

Basically you can regulate the speed of any PC that connects.

Here is a WIP for a FrontEnd - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=442200

MasterShaper Web Interface - http://www.mastershaper.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: This popped up in a low-quality queue. Maybe update it with some instructions?

Comment: @muru Thank you buddy. Let me update it this weekend. It's a "bit" old... just a bit. ;)

Comment: It is *old*.  And it looks like this question is going to be closed as a dupe and yours is the accepted answer there, so maybe you don't need to do anything at all, except add your vote as well.