# How do I limit internet bandwidth?

Tags: software-recommendation, resource-limiting

I am getting complaints that I consume lots of internet bandwidth.

Is there any software that can limit internet bandwidth on my computer from my own computer? I use Firefox as browser and use bittorrent and download software from software center.

(Is there also a way to monitor it?)

Comment: Setting a firewall for advertising or non-wanting IPs would also diminish the bandwidth

Comment: use the tc command with iptables, use tcpump or iperf to monitor it

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You have 2 easy to use via terminal. Wondershaper and Trickle. There are more here: [How to limit internet speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18038/how-to-limit-internet-speed)

Anyway the basics are:

```
sudo apt-get install wondershaper
```

In terminal find out what is the name of the interface connected to your internet by using `ifconfig`. Could be eth0, eth1, eth2, etc... In my case is eth1. So, I would do this:

```
sudo wondershaper eth1 1024 256
```

This will give me a Download speed of 1024 Kbits and 256 Kbits Upload. Which are 128KB and 16KB.

If you want to reset that do this `sudo wondershaper clear eth1`

NOTE: That will limit ANYTHING in your PC, for example the torrent downloader, firefox, etc..

Another program is **Trickle**

To install do this:

```
sudo apt-get install trickle
```

To run `firefox` with a maximum of 120KB/s download and 32KB/s upload, run

```
trickle -d 120 -u 32 firefox
```

In my case I recommend wondershaper.

If you want more info for any of the two after installed type `man wondershaper` or `man trickle` depending on the one you installed.

Comment: Is it possible to limit/reverse internet bandwidth for each program instead of per device?

Comment: @Nur For what I know, it is possible but involves some kernel editing and other stuff outside of the user space. It would be awesome to have a similar approach as tools like the Windows Netlimiter. Of course netlimiter connects a process that manages the connection sharing, but the idea remains the same and would help a lot in network cases where this applies.

Comment: Trickle can do that http://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth
`trickle -u (upload limit in KB/s) -d (download limit in KB/s) application`

Comment: WARNING: as of writing this comment trickle only works for 32-bit operating systems, it does not support 64-bit

Comment: @KarlMorrison Thank you. VERY important to know that. +1

Comment: I might have to rephase because a person was able to get it working on 64bit vivid apparantly. I put a bug report in the github if you want to see more. Im running 14.04 and it does not work.

Comment: I recommend putting the link to the bug report here, so anyone with the same issue can go there quickly.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Trickle is part of debian 32 and 64bit.

Comment: I'm not able to use the version of Wondershaper in Ubuntu 19.04. It limits bandwidth, yes, to about 300 bytes per second, regardless of the desired speed I put in.

Comment: @krubo Thank you for the feedback. I also test this and although at around 250kb to 1MB I did not noticed anything, when I got to 10MB, 25MB and 100MB, everything got stuck in around 1.5MB, so yes, there is some bug with wondershaper. I suggest going to their site and posting this as a bug.

Comment: @krubo The values you give to wondershaper are in kilobits per second. 300 bytes per second is barely even possible, the lowest value you can give is 1 (1000 bits per second), which is 125 bytes per second. It is as if you gave "3" in the parameter. I know people don't love hearing this: wondershaper works perfectly for me (in 18.04 LTS). LTS for the win.

Comment: @doug65536 yes, that was a long time ago. I assume they changed the minimum and the unit used for it. Have not tried it for years.