# How to monitor bandwidth usage per process?

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. My internet connection is pretty slow (512 kbps). Sometimes I see that I have no software running which should download anything from the internet, but the system monitor still shows that some download is going on. So I think some hidden software are causing this. Is there a way I can monitor every software that is using internet?

Comment: @Braiam: That question is about monitoring *total* network data usage across system restarts.

Comment: @codeaviator: I think the answers on this question are better than on the one behind your link. We should either have the duplicate flag point the other way around or merge them altogether. I'm raising a flag for the latter.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Good point.  I'm raising a moderator flag in favor of merging both questions.

Comment: distro agnostic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368002/network-usage-top-htop-on-linux

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use [nethogs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nethogs) [image: Install nethogs] tool to monitor all your traffic on an interface.

Install it using

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Now run it using

```
sudo nethogs <interface name>
```

For example

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

[image]

For more detail type [`man nethogs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/nethogs.8.html) after installing.

Comment: Anyway to set bandwidth parameters on the applications?

Comment: No, this tool only monitors bandwidth. If you are looking for something similar to bandwidth shaping, you can refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth) post.

Comment: If you have 'creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?' despite being root, then see the answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/729560/67747

Comment: Brilliant just what i was looking for!

Comment: `sudo nethogs eth0` for default.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer `sudo netstat -tunap`

```
vinny@vinny-Bonobo-Extreme:~$ sudo netstat -tunap 
[sudo] password for vinny: 
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1160/minidlnad  
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      927/dnsmasq     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2543/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.10:58491      198.252.206.149:443     ESTABLISHED 30401/firefox   
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.10:39824      173.194.219.189:443     ESTABLISHED 30401/firefox   
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.10:58569      198.252.206.149:443     ESTABLISHED 30401/firefox   
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.10:59283      173.194.219.18:443      ESTABLISHED 30401/firefox   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2543/cupsd      
tcp6       1      0 ::1:60390               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  863/cups-browsed
tcp6       1      0 ::1:34718               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  1469/plasmashell
tcp6       1      0 ::1:60391               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  863/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           1160/minidlnad  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10097           0.0.0.0:*                           26759/dhclient  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           759/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39609           0.0.0.0:*                           759/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 192.168.2.10:57168      0.0.0.0:*                           1160/minidlnad  
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           927/dnsmasq     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           26759/dhclient  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           863/cups-browsed
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                759/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::13818                :::*                                26759/dhclient  
udp6       0      0 :::39404                :::*                                759/avahi-daemon: r
```

shows even system proses that is using the network and the name of them.

but not really a monitor as you half to keep running it to see changing output.

Comment: doesn't work on macOS.

Comment: As suggested below, [sudo watch -n1 netstat -tunap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532424/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage-per-process) is a nice varation on this answer.

Comment: Another [useful contribution](https://askubuntu.com/a/532431/226416): -n option is to show numerical address (ip) to which connection is established, -p is program which has established that connection, and -t lists all tcplimits to tcp connections.

Answer (score 10):

Just a bit more comfort with netstat `sudo watch -n1 netstat -tunap`

It will refresh the data each 1s

Comment: This should be an edit to the existing answer above...

Comment: @Fabby I've made it a comment on the answer above.

Answer (score 6):

The `iptraf` utility is another way to monitor the traffic, provided by the [iptraf](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/iptraf) [image: Install iptraf] package. `sudo apt-get install iptraf` installs it.

<sup>`iptraf` is available in Red Hat Linux also; run `yum install iptraf` as root to install it.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Terminal tool:    `netstat -tnp` . -n option is to show numerical address (ip) to which connection is established, -p is program which has established that connection, and -t lists all tcplimits to tcp connections. Alternativelly, you could use `netstat -a > networkscan.txt` to output everything into a txt file

Answer (score 1):

#### [Socket Statistics, `ss`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss)

`ss` is the [modern alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278474/209677) to `netstat`.

```
sudo apt install iproute2  # Install
```

Usage example:

```
watch -n1 sudo ss -ntp  # Do not try to resolve service names. TCP. View processes
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern alternative to ss by now :)

[ss2(pyroute)](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/blob/master/cli/ss2)

Comment: While this link may answer the question,it's better to include essential parts here.