# Nethogs → creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, nethogs

Following update of my Kubuntu, I'm not able to monitor my network consumption using `nethogs`:

```
sudo nethogs enp1s0
creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?
```

#### Kernel

```
$ uname -a
Linux xyz 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### Release

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
```

#### Version

```
$ nethogs -V
version 0.8.0
```

Comment: it even crashes here..., the github one seems good tho

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This is [solved by version `0.8.1`](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/issues/9).

As it's not available in repo nor PPA you **need to build it** (it is really **easy and quickly done**).

#### Fetch and extract the most recent version (as of August 2016, v0.8.5)

```
wget -c https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/archive/v0.8.5.tar.gz
tar xf v0.8.5.tar.gz 
cd ./nethogs-0.8.5/
```

#### Install dependencies and build

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libpcap-dev
make && sudo make install
```

#### Check and run

```
nethogs -V
sudo nethogs
```

Comment: Better with checkinstall that we can manage it easily, also avoiding conflict with the default repo from ubuntu. Just check license and version to update this command: `make && sudo -k checkinstall --pkgsource="https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/" --pkglicense="GPL2" --deldesc=no --nodoc --maintainer="$USER\\<$USER@$HOSTNAME\\>" --pkgarch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) --pkgversion="0.8.2" --pkgrelease="SNAPSHOT" --pkgname=nethogs make install`.

Comment: @AquariusPower thank, I'm not familiar with `checkinstall`. BTW didn't you forget a `&&` before the  `make install`?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez checkinstall will call `make install` and track everything it does to create a deb package :)

Comment: You can use ``checkinstall`` if you want it to update when the next versions roll in

Comment: This worked, but after running this answer's command, `nethogs -V` still reports my previous version, v0.8.0. `sudo nethogs -V` reports v0.8.1, and opening a new terminal and running `nethogs -V` reports v0.8.1.  I'm just curious why.

Comment: @TylerCollier the $PATH variable was probably updated and need to be reexported so you can access correct version. You can install the synaptic package and check where it is installed with `which nethogs`, then reinstall from source and check again to see if the path changes.

Comment: I can confirm the command from @AquariusPower works in gNewSense 4 Ucclia (upgraded into Debian Jessie) perfectly. I am using NetHogs 0.8.1 now. My binary of nethogs here belongs to */usr/local/sbin/nethogs*. Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you originally installed nethogs v0.8.0 via apt-get or another package manager then this method does not remove it. E.g. on my Ubuntu 14.04 system nethogs v0.8.5 is installed in /usr/local/sbin/nethogs, but v0.8.0 is still available in /usr/sbin/nethogs

Comment: @cfogelberg edwinksl the bug is supposed to be fixed in 0.8.1, if that's not the case, please [repoen the issue](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/issues/9)

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez I believe it is fixed in 0.8.1, the latest version is 0.8.5 though so I just made a quick edit to the answer so that other users who just used these instructions would default to installing the (current) latest  version with the idea that later is better and presumably has other bug fixes too

Answer (score 6):

You can also build from latest source code in the git repository. You still need to install the dependency packages first. After building you can run `nethogs` from your current directory:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libpcap-dev
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/raboof/nethogs.git
cd nethogs
make
sudo ./src/nethogs
```

You can also find the instructions on the [Nethogs project page](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/).

Comment: Please do not just dump a bunch of commands here but also explain what they do and why you think they solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think is self explanatory, 1 - install the software dependencies, 2 -  download the latest source from Git, 3 - goes to the newly created directory, 4 - compiles the program, 5 - runs the program

Comment: I've added the requested explanation in the answer and a link to the official instructions.

Comment: Not everybody has git nor want's to install it. Dowloading the tar and building is good enough.

Comment: the current repo compiles the executable into the src/ subdirectory, so the last command needs to be `sudo src/nethogs`