# how can I find connection info of an application which is currently downloading at top speed?

Tags: networking, connection

I noticed from the `InfoPanel` screenlet that my computer downloading something at high speed. I was not downloading anything and I already ran `apt-get upgrade` so there was no apparent reason for my comp to download something. I tried to run some well known network checking commands but they didn't help much since they don't list connections by speed rate:

```
netstat -A inet -p | grep '^tcp' | grep '/' | sed 's_.*/__' | sort | uniq

ss -tp | grep -v Recv-Q | sed -e 's/.*users:(("//' -e 's/".*$//' | sort | uniq
```

Is there any tool you know that lists connections by speed rate like command `top` does ?

Comment: `nethogs` was the best one --- but it is not working in my system now. Hmm....

Comment: Ah, ok: http://askubuntu.com/questions/726601/nethogs-%E2%86%92-creating-socket-failed-while-establishing-local-ip-are-you-root (this site is just incredible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)

Comment: `nethogs` seems to be what I want. It's pity that we have no alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best tool is [`nethogs`](http://raboof.github.io/nethogs/).

Unfortunately, the version available in Ubuntu 14.04 is broken, so you have to compile it yourself: See [Nethogs → creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726601/nethogs-%E2%86%92-creating-socket-failed-while-establishing-local-ip-are-you-root).

After that, just run:

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

where `wlan0` is the name of the interface you want to monitor.

[image: example of nethogs running]

Use `q` to exit.