# How to observe requests sent by console application?

Tags: command-line, networking, monitoring, url

I want to monitor what requests some command line tool is making. App itself doesn't show this information only final result. Is there any option to watch the urls to which this application sends request?

Comment: Do you mean "monitor network or internet traffic?"

Comment: @Redbob I mean internet traffic. Application requests some data from internet resources. And I want to know which resources it uses.

Comment: Probably a duplicated issue. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/532424/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage

Comment: Look into Wireshark.