# VPS bandwidth spike exactly once every hour

Tags: networking, 18.04, vps, bandwidth

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a digitalocean droplet.

Here you can see the [DigitalOcean bandwidth monitor graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk5SH.jpg)

As you can see in the image the spikes occur exactly once every hour. According to the digitalocean monitor they start at `hour:50minutes` and they stop at `nextHour:10minutes` the peak being at `hour:00 minutes`.

I am new to ubuntu and I don't know how to find out what is causing those spikes.Please help :D.

Comment: sounds like you're being either hit hard during that time period *or* you're producing a lot of traffic.  Your service(s) haven't been under attack or hijacked have they?

Comment: Using nethogs as suggested below I found the problem. There was a process I installed that was syncing data every hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very popular question.

I would suggest to to install Nethogs

> sudo apt-get install nethogs

Then, if you want to check your internet traffic.

> sudo nethogs eth0

If you want to check your LAN traffic (VPS)

> sudo nethogs eth1

Here You have some links to possible answers.
1.
[How to monitor bandwidth usage per process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532424/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage-per-process/532430)
2.
[How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)

Comment: Is there any nethogs command for history? I mean I have to monitor nethogs exactly when the spike happens but I am wondering if I could watch activity that already happened. In my situation I know when the spike happens but what if I didn't and the spikes were random