# Can I limit how much wifi I use

Tags: wireless

I don't want to be hogging up my wifi network. Can I limit how much wifi I use so I don't hog up the network I am using and if so how?

Comment: please clarify a bit more what exactly do you want to limit? you want to reduce the speed or rather download data amount? or something else?

Comment: I want to limit my computer so that other people connected to the network don't get slow internet speeds

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a way to limit the speed at which your wifi connects. This question was [already answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth).

Perhaps [wondershaper](http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2011/01/limit-internet-bandwidth-usage-internet.html) will do what you need. It will limit upload and download speeds independently. Quoting from the article:

```
sudo apt-get install wondershaper
```

Now issue a command similar to following (replacing eth0 with your interface name):

```
sudo wondershaper eth0 1024 256
```

this will limit the download speed to 1024 Kbps and upload to 256 Kbps. Remember that this limit is for all internet traffic i.e torrent, ftp, browsing and any thing else.

If you want to remove these limits use

```
sudo wondershaper clear eth0
```

Comment: it be better if you include the essential parts from that link in your answer and at the bottom post that link as a refferance, because that link might get deleted or moved in the future and will not be accessible any more.

Comment: Does mtu have anything to do with it

Comment: Does mtu have anything to do with Limiting bandwidth

Comment: @jo900 that's a bit different and long to talk look [here](http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=190)